How can I share LTE modem internet over Wifi?
I've got my LTE modem setup with NetworkManager/ModemManager and that's working fine. I've also got Wifi setup as an access point in NetworkManager with DHCP.
But how can I share the LTE modem internet access over Wifi? I've enabled IP forwarding (echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward), what else is there?
# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12946 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12946 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1297231 (1.2 MiB)  TX bytes:1297231 (1.2 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr E8:4F:25:DD:BD:51
          inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ea4f:25ff:fedd:bd51/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:12101 (11.8 KiB)

wwan0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:100.72.254.176  P-t-P:100.72.254.176  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2176 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:356293 (347.9 KiB)  TX bytes:261384 (255.2 KiB)

# ip route
default via 100.72.254.177 dev wwan0  metric 700
10.42.0.0/24 dev wlan0 scope link  src 10.42.0.1  metric 600
100.72.254.160/27 dev wwan0 scope link  src 100.72.254.176  metric 700

The DHCP for the Wifi is done by NetworkManager starting dnsmasq with default parameters:
# ps -eF | grep dnsmasq
nobody      1104     606  0  1285  2444   0 09:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/dev/null --no-hosts --keep-in-foreground --bind-interfaces --except-interface=lo --clear-on-reload --strict-order --listen-address=10.42.0.1 --dhcp-range=10.42.0.10,10.42.0.254,60m --dhcp-lease-max=50 --dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-wlan0.leases --pid-file=/var/run/nm-dnsmasq-wlan0.pid --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d

ref NetworkManager and dnsmasq dhcp address range).
# cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ap.nmconnection
[connection]
id=ap
uuid=3205b229-8c4d-4766-8d63-bcd949d03321
type=wifi
autoconnect=false
interface-name=wlan0

[wifi]
band=bg
channel=1
mode=ap
ssid=MySSID

[wifi-security]
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=MyPSK

[ipv4]
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=ignore

[proxy]

A colleague suggested https://github.com/oblique/create_ap. I tried both the NAT and bridge options but they both failed.
NAT:
# create_ap -w 2 wlan0 wwan0 APTest 12345678
WARN: brmfmac driver doesn't work properly with virtual interfaces and
      it can cause kernel panic. For this reason we disallow virtual
      interfaces for your adapter.
      For more info: https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/203
WARN: Your adapter does not fully support AP virtual interface, enabling --no-virt
Config dir: /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.XX59Vdf8
PID: 537195
Network Manager found, set wlan0 as unmanaged device... [46988.754925] ieee80211 phy1: brcmf_set_pmk: failed to change PSK in firmware (len=0)
[46988.784848] ieee80211 phy1: brcmf_vif_set_mgmt_ie: vndr ie set error : -52
[46988.792027] ieee80211 phy1: brcmf_vif_set_mgmt_ie: vndr ie set error : -52
DONE
Sharing Internet using method: nat
iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): unknown option "--to-ports"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Doing cleanup.. done

Bridge:
# create_ap -w 2 -m bridge wlan0 wwan0 APTest 12345678
WARN: brmfmac driver doesn't work properly with virtual interfaces and
      it can cause kernel panic. For this reason we disallow virtual
      interfaces for your adapter.
      For more info: https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/203
WARN: Your adapter does not fully support AP virtual interface, enabling --no-virt
Config dir: /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.XXgGPNON
PID: 540585
Network Manager found, set wlan0 as unmanaged device... DONE
Sharing Internet using method: bridge
Create a bridge interface... ip: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported


Could we get some clarification on the hardware for the LTE modem? I'm assuming it is a one port, wired only device, or is it a MiFi/hotspot device?  I'm also assuming in the case of a wired only modem, it is plugged directly into your Linux machine, and you're trying to get said machine to broadcast over WiFi, yes?

It's a USB connected LTE modem plugged in directly.

Following https://community.unix.com/t/iptables-v1-8-7-nf-tables-unknown-option-to-ports/385377/7, I added strace to my device:
# strace iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid 0
execve("/usr/sbin/iptables", ["iptables", "-A", "OUTPUT", "-m", "owner", "--uid", "0"], 0x7ffa7423d0 /* 29 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55a5afa000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f8502f000
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=32961, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 32961, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f85026000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libip4tc.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=31152, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 160296, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f84fd1000
mmap(0x7f84fe0000, 94760, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f84fe0000
munmap(0x7f84fd1000, 61440)             = 0
munmap(0x7f84ff8000, 552)               = 0
mprotect(0x7f84fe7000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f84ff6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f84ff6000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libip6tc.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=31152, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 160296, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f84fb8000
mmap(0x7f84fc0000, 94760, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f84fc0000
munmap(0x7f84fb8000, 32768)             = 0
munmap(0x7f84fd8000, 29224)             = 0
mprotect(0x7f84fc7000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f84fd6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f84fd6000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libxtables.so.12", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=59304, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 199720, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f84f8f000
mmap(0x7f84f90000, 134184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f84f90000
munmap(0x7f84f8f000, 4096)              = 0
munmap(0x7f84fb1000, 60456)             = 0
mprotect(0x7f84f9e000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f84fad000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xd000) = 0x7f84fad000
mmap(0x7f84faf000, 7208, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f84faf000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0@\264\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0/\267c\324\361R\25\177\n\177\26\327\322\277\4\211"..., 68, 768) = 68
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1630088, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1805328, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f84dd7000
mmap(0x7f84de0000, 1739792, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f84de0000
munmap(0x7f84dd7000, 36864)             = 0
munmap(0x7f84f89000, 27664)             = 0
mprotect(0x7f84f68000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f84f77000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x187000) = 0x7f84f77000
mmap(0x7f84f7d000, 48144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f84f7d000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f85024000
set_tid_address(0x7f850240f0)           = 25050
set_robust_list(0x7f85024100, 24)       = 0
rseq(0x7f850247c0, 0x20, 0, 0xd428bc00) = 0
mprotect(0x7f84f77000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f84fad000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f84fd6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f84ff6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x557a8bc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f85033000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7f85026000, 32961)             = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/xtables/libipt_owner.so", 0x7fdac3dc78, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/xtables/libxt_owner.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18904, ...}, 0) = 0
getrandom("\x89\xee\xcc\x55\xdc\x6d\x75\xd8", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55a5afa000
brk(0x55a5b1b000)                       = 0x55a5b1b000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/xtables/libxt_owner.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18904, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 148048, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f84dbb000
mmap(0x7f84dc0000, 82512, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f84dc0000
munmap(0x7f84dbb000, 20480)             = 0
munmap(0x7f84dd5000, 41552)             = 0
mprotect(0x7f84dc3000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f84dd3000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f84dd3000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f84dd3000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)  = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/ip_tables_names", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0440, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
statfs("/proc/net/ip_tables_names", {f_type=PROC_SUPER_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={val=[0, 0]}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_NOSUID|ST_NODEV|ST_NOEXEC|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_MATCH, 0x7fdac3db68, [30]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)  = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_MATCH, 0x7fdac3db68, [30]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): ", 26iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): ) = 26
write(2, "Couldn't load match `owner':No s"..., 54Couldn't load match `owner':No such file or directory
) = 54
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(2, "Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables -"..., 61Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
) = 61
exit_group(2)                           = ?
+++ exited with 2 +++

Looks like we're missing /usr/lib/xtables/libipt_owner.so. https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-754259-start-0.html suggests this requires CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_OWNER=m so I tried that:
# iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid 0

Interestingly when running strace on the working command the line that changes is getsockopt, from:
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/ip_tables_names", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0440, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
statfs("/proc/net/ip_tables_names", {f_type=PROC_SUPER_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={val=[0, 0]}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_NOSUID|ST_NODEV|ST_NOEXEC|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_MATCH, 0x7fdac3db68, [30]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

to:
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/ip_tables_names", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0440, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
statfs("/proc/net/ip_tables_names", {f_type=PROC_SUPER_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={val=[0, 0]}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_NOSUID|ST_NODEV|ST_NOEXEC|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_MATCH, "owner\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1", [30]) = 0

NAT still fails, so try {{strace}} again:
# strace iptables -w -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.12.0/24 -d 192.168.12.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5353
execve("/usr/sbin/iptables", ["iptables", "-w", "-t", "nat", "-I", "PREROUTING", "-s", "192.168.12.0/24", "-d", "192.168.12.1", "-p", "tcp", "-m", "tcp", "--dport", "53", "-j", "REDIRECT", "--to-ports", "5353"], 0x7ff90c7de8 /* 29 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55b6039000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb4e97000
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=32961, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 32961, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb4e8e000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libip4tc.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=31152, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 160296, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb4e39000
mmap(0x7fb4e40000, 94760, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb4e40000
munmap(0x7fb4e39000, 28672)             = 0
munmap(0x7fb4e58000, 33320)             = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4e47000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb4e56000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7fb4e56000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libip6tc.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=31152, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 160296, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb4e18000
mmap(0x7fb4e20000, 94760, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb4e20000
munmap(0x7fb4e18000, 32768)             = 0
munmap(0x7fb4e38000, 29224)             = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4e27000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb4e36000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7fb4e36000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libxtables.so.12", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=59304, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 199720, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb4def000
mmap(0x7fb4df0000, 134184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb4df0000
munmap(0x7fb4def000, 4096)              = 0
munmap(0x7fb4e11000, 60456)             = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4dfe000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb4e0d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xd000) = 0x7fb4e0d000
mmap(0x7fb4e0f000, 7208, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb4e0f000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0@\264\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0/\267c\324\361R\25\177\n\177\26\327\322\277\4\211"..., 68, 768) = 68
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1630088, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1805328, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb4c37000
mmap(0x7fb4c40000, 1739792, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb4c40000
munmap(0x7fb4c37000, 36864)             = 0
munmap(0x7fb4de9000, 27664)             = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4dc8000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb4dd7000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x187000) = 0x7fb4dd7000
mmap(0x7fb4ddd000, 48144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb4ddd000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb4e8c000
set_tid_address(0x7fb4e8c0f0)           = 83953
set_robust_list(0x7fb4e8c100, 24)       = 0
rseq(0x7fb4e8c7c0, 0x20, 0, 0xd428bc00) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4dd7000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4e0d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4e36000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4e56000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x558371f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4e9b000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7fb4e8e000, 32961)             = 0
getrandom("\xfa\xf8\xa1\x00\x5e\xc6\xd6\x38", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55b6039000
brk(0x55b605a000)                       = 0x55b605a000
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=482, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=482, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# Example"..., 4096) = 482
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=482, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=32961, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 32961, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb4e8e000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/aarch64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/aarch64", 0x7fe4e67730, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls", 0x7fe4e67730, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64", 0x7fe4e67730, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/aarch64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/aarch64", 0x7fe4e67730, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls", 0x7fe4e67730, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/aarch64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/aarch64", 0x7fe4e67730, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=32768, ...}, 0) = 0
munmap(0x7fb4e8e000, 32961)             = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/protocols", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2932, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "# Internet (IP) protocols\n#\n# Up"..., 4096) = 2932
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/xtables/libipt_tcp.so", 0x7fe4e68508, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/xtables/libxt_tcp.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=14424, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/xtables/libxt_tcp.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=14424, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 143568, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb4c1c000
mmap(0x7fb4c20000, 78032, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb4c20000
munmap(0x7fb4c1c000, 16384)             = 0
munmap(0x7fb4c34000, 45264)             = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4c23000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb4c32000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fb4c32000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4c32000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)  = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/ip_tables_names", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0440, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
statfs("/proc/net/ip_tables_names", {f_type=PROC_SUPER_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={val=[0, 0]}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_NOSUID|ST_NODEV|ST_NOEXEC|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_MATCH, "tcp\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", [30]) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/xtables/libipt_REDIRECT.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=10344, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/xtables/libipt_REDIRECT.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=10344, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 139480, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb4bfd000
mmap(0x7fb4c00000, 73944, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb4c00000
munmap(0x7fb4bfd000, 12288)             = 0
munmap(0x7fb4c13000, 49368)             = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4c02000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb4c11000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7fb4c11000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fb4c11000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)  = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_TARGET, 0x7fe4e683e8, [30]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): ", 26iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): ) = 26
write(2, "unknown option \"--to-ports\"", 27unknown option "--to-ports") = 27
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(2, "Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables -"..., 61Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
) = 61
exit_group(2)                           = ?
+++ exited with 2 +++

Previously we had a failure with IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_MATCH, now it's IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_TARGET. I looked for usage of this in the Linux source for v5.4.238:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.238/C/ident/IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_TARGET
They're used in the same function.
I also noticed that if you run without --to-ports you get:
# iptables -w -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.12.0/24 -d 192.168.12.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT
iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): Couldn't load target `REDIRECT':No such file or directory

So if adding CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_OWNER fixed IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_MATCH, would adding CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_REDIRECT fix IPT_SO_GET_REVISION_TARGET?
Yes it does, NAT method now works.

For IPv4, the pieces you need are:

Access WiFi access point (you have it)
IPv4 Forwarding (you've enabled it)
Configured WAN device (you have it)
NAT between WIFI access point and WAN (you've not mentioned it).

What's a NAT and why do you need one?
Accross the internet all IP addresses are registered (in blocks) with IANA.  The internet itself organises routing for every registered IP address [block], so the IP address alone tells each router where to forward packets to.
But your local network IP address (10.42.0.x in your case) are not registerd with IANA and internet routers don't know how to find you. You don't own that address anyway, but it's reserved for anyone to use like this.
Network Address Translation swaps local IP address on outgoing packets with the router's own [public] IP address so that servers on the internet see the router's public IP address, not a device's local network IP address.  The router then does reverse swap for incoming packets before sending them back to local devices.
Setting up a NAT with iptables
Don't forget you might need sudo and don't forget that iptables to not save on reboot normally.  Instructions on how to persist iptables rules in Ubuntu can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/84781/iptables-resets-when-server-reboots
The iptables rule:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i wlan0 -o wwan0 -j MASQUERADE


That gives me iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): Can't use -i with POSTROUTING

I tried iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wwan0 -j MASQUERADE from
https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-4.html#ss4.1 but I still don't get internet from the Wifi.

If it’s something else you may need to give a lot more information, like the configuration of DHCP server.

Added DHCP details.
